# How to make a function inside the tikzpicture behave like outside

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, robust-commands

I have a macro which generates a structure (rule) and a reference to that structure. It does not behave when inside a `tikzpicture`. How to make the function robust to reference the structure even when inside tikzpicture? 
(I also want to get rid of the error message "mevp not defined")

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\makeatletter
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcounter{strctz}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\strct}[1]{%
%  \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\c#1}} %
%     {
       \refstepcounter{strctz}%
       \textbf{#1}\textbf{\Large({\thestrctz})}%
       \\[2mm]%
       \rule{2cm}{5mm}%
       \begingroup
       \expandafter\protected@edef\csname c#1\endcsname{\thestrctz}%
       \expandafter\endgroup
       \expandafter\DeclareRobustCommand
       \csname c#1\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\endcsname
       \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\csname c#1\endcsname}%
 %    }
 %    {#1%
 %    \\[2mm]%
 %    \rule{2cm}{5mm}%
 %      (\c#1)%
 %    }
 }
 \makeatother
 \begin{document}
 \strct{mevalonate}
 (\cmevalonate) and

  \strct{ohpregnenolone}

  Structure (\cohpregnenolone) and structure (\cmevalonate) and
  Structure (\cohpregnenolone)

 \strct{alanine}  and (\calanine) (\cmevalonate) (\cohpregnenolone)

 \strct{mevalonate}

  %Isoprenyl-Bildung, Dimethyl-Allyl-Bildung aus Mevalonat
 %
  \tikzstyle{prenPP}= [rectangle,minimum size=2.4cm,text width=3.8cm,text  centered,inner sep=.05cm]
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \node [prenPP%
         ,text width=4.6cm%
        ]      (mev)        at (0,8) {\strct{mevalonate}};
   node [prenPP%
         ,text width=4.6cm%
   ] (mevP)       at (8,8) {\strct{mevalonateP}};
   \draw[->,shorten >=0.5cm,shorten <=0.5cm,very thick]
     (mev)   -- node[below=0.5pt] {\parbox{2.5cm}{%
       \begin{center}%
         enzym{mevalonate kinase}
       \end{center}}}%
     (mevP) ;
   \end{tikzpicture}
 \cmelonalonateP
 \end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436). It would be helpful if you turned your code snippet into a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem. While solving problems can be fun, setting them up is not. Then, those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving the problem.

Comment: Paul Gaborit did it for me. Thank you, Paul

Comment: I can't get it to compile at all.  No error message, it just hangs.

Comment: I have code which compiles here well. I would like to add the ifthenelse part but then breaks even the macros outside the tikz environnement. I am at a loss.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically this is a typo - the macro you call at the end, `\cmelonalonateP`, is not the one, `\cmevalonateP`, defined in the node.  Additionally the unknown shape comes from a missing `\` before the corresponding defining node command.

However, `ifthenelse` would be much better replaced by using macros from the package `etoolbox`.  This would allow you to shorten the code and make it clearer.  In particular `etoolbox` provides `\ifcsdef`, `\csuse` and `\protected@csxdef` amongst other things, which work with macro names rather than you having to issue `\csname...\endcsname` and keep track of expansion.

For example

```
\ifcsdef{c#1}{TRUE}{FALSE}
```

checks whether the macro `\` followed by `c` and then the contents of `#1` is defined and acts accordingly.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz,etoolbox}
\newcounter{strctz}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\strct}[1]{%
  \ifcsdef{c#1}{%
    #1\\[2mm]%
    \rule{2cm}{5mm}%
      (\csuse{c#1})%
    }{%
       \refstepcounter{strctz}%
       \textbf{#1}\textbf{ -- def. ({\thestrctz})}%
       \\[2mm]%
       \rule{2cm}{5mm}%
       \protected@csxdef{c#1}{\thestrctz}%
       \expandafter\DeclareRobustCommand
       \csname c#1\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\endcsname
       \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\csname c#1\endcsname}%
    }%
 }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\parindent=0pt

\strct{mevalonate} (\cmevalonate) and

\strct{ohpregnenolone}

Structure (\cohpregnenolone) and structure (\cmevalonate) and
structure (\cohpregnenolone)

\strct{alanine}  and (\calanine) (\cmevalonate) (\cohpregnenolone)

\strct{mevalonate}

\tikzstyle{prenPP}=[rectangle, minimum size=2.4cm, text width=3.8cm,
  text centered, inner sep=.05cm]
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node [prenPP,text width=4.6cm]
  (mev) at (0,8) {\strct{mevalonate}};
  \node [prenPP,text width=4.6cm]
  (mevP) at (8,8) {\strct{mevalonateP}};
  \draw[->,shorten >=0.5cm,shorten <=0.5cm,very thick]
  (mev)   -- node[below=0.5pt] {\parbox{2.5cm}{%
  \begin{center}%
    enzym{mevalonate kinase}
  \end{center}}}%
  (mevP) ;
\end{tikzpicture}

Here we see (\cmevalonateP) is defined.

\end{document}
```

[image: Sample output]